# How do I upload JSON data to Cloudant in bulk?

Tags: json, couchdb, cloudant

I'm trying to upload a 50Mb json file to a Cloudant database and I've tried over curl and using a NodeJS script. I get

```js
{"error":"too_large","reason":"the request entity is too large"}
```

but if I limit it to 1000 documents, it works.What is the fastest way of doing this , am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Cloudant has a document [size limit of 1MB](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Cloudant?topic=Cloudant-limits) and each individual request must be [less than 10MB](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Cloudant?topic=Cloudant-limits). So if you need to upload 50MB of data, the work needs to be distributed amongst several API calls. I would recommend you use the [_bulk_docs API](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/cloudant#postbulkdocs) to upload 500 documents per API call. You may have several API calls in flight at any one time.